# Excel - Denormalized data

Tags: xml, excel

I'm able to import this XML file in Excel :

```
<MTXML  Version = "2.2"  xmlns:xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation = "mtxml.xsd">
    <Records  FolderName = "Weld">
       <Records  FolderName = "High Strength Steel">
          <Record  ID = "Tata">
             <Metadata>
                <Name>Toto
                </Name>
                <OwnerName>Test
                </OwnerName>
             </Metadata>
             <Datasets>
                <Dataset  DatasetID = "50084"  IDref = "FortranStatus">
                   <String>
                      <Value>aaa
                      </Value>
                   </String>
                </Dataset>
                <Dataset  DatasetID = "1"  IDref = "Thermal_conductivity_weld">
                   <Float>
                      <Curve  Label = "Curve1">
                         <DataAxis>
                            <ValueList>
                               <a>3.400000e-002
                               </a>
                               <b>3.600000e-002
                               </b>                            
                            </ValueList>
                         </DataAxis>
                         <ParameterAxis  IDref = "TEMP">
                            <ValueList>
                               <a>0.000000e+000
                               </a>
                               <b>2.000000e+002
                               </b>                            
                            </ValueList>
                         </ParameterAxis>
                         <ParameterFixed  IDref = "Selected_Phases">
                            <Value>Ferrite
                            </Value>
                         </ParameterFixed>
                      </Curve>
                   </Float>
                </Dataset>          
            </Datasets>
          </Record>
       </Records>
    </Records>
 </MTXML>
```

But if I modify some values and I try to export this, I have an error message : 'Denormalized data'

Could you explain why it doesn't work ? I don't see where is the error...

Thanks !